# BeautifulSoup does not delete tags containing "text like" tags correctly

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have this post taken from [How do I avoid showing header and footer on the last page using dompdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310116/how-do-i-avoid-showing-header-and-footer-on-the-last-page-using-dompdf)

as you can see, the post itself contains code. what i want to do is to remove the codes correctly
**i want to use my own string (and not taking the html from a request)**, and remove the code from the htmls, but somehow it does not remove img tags correctly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
chtml='''<p>My app exports a several pages report with a header and a footer. Header and footer should however not appear on the first and last pages.</p>
<p>By placing the first page out of the <code>main</code> tag, I managed to take the header out of it. However the same does not work for the last page. </p>
<p>How do I remove the header and footer from the last page?</p>
<p><body>
    <div class="page">
        <img ...>
    </div></p>
<pre><code>&lt;header&gt;
    &lt;img ...&gt;
&lt;/header&gt;

&lt;footer&gt;
    ...
&lt;/footer&gt;

&lt;main&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/main&gt;

&lt;div class="page"&gt;
    &lt;img ...&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</code></pre>
<p></body></p>
<pre><code>@page { margin: 80px 40px 0px 40px; }
@page:first {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: -40px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 40px;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
</code></pre>'''
csoup = BeautifulSoup(chtml, "lxml")
for s in csoup.select('code'):
  s.extract()
print(csoup)
```

i get the output:

```
<html><body><p>My app exports a several pages report with a header and a footer. Header and footer should however not appear on the first and last pages.</p>
<p>By placing the first page out of the  tag, I managed to take the header out of it. However the same does not work for the last page. </p>
<p>How do I remove the header and footer from the last page?</p>
<p></p>
<div class="page">
<img ...=""/>
</div>
<pre></pre>
<p></p>
<pre></pre></body></html>
```

what can i do so that this part will not appear?

```
<div class="page">
<img ...=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand what you want but i guess you want it like this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
chtml='''<p>My app exports a several pages report with a header and a footer. Header and footer should however not appear on the first and last pages.</p>
<p>By placing the first page out of the <code>main</code> tag, I managed to take the header out of it. However the same does not work for the last page. </p>
<p>How do I remove the header and footer from the last page?</p>
<p><body>
    <div class="page">
        <img ...>
    </div></p>
<pre><code>&lt;header&gt;
    &lt;img ...&gt;
&lt;/header&gt;

&lt;footer&gt;
    ...
&lt;/footer&gt;

&lt;main&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/main&gt;

&lt;div class="page"&gt;
    &lt;img ...&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</code></pre>
<p></body></p>
<pre><code>@page { margin: 80px 40px 0px 40px; }
@page:first {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: -40px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 40px;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
</code></pre>'''
csoup = BeautifulSoup(chtml, "lxml")
for s in csoup.select('code'):
  s.extract()


soup = BeautifulSoup(str(csoup), 'lxml')
for div in soup.select('div.page'):
    div.extract()

print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   My app exports a several pages report with a header and a footer. Header and footer should however not appear on the first and last pages.
  </p>
  <p>
   By placing the first page out of the  tag, I managed to take the header out of it. However the same does not work for the last page.
  </p>
  <p>
   How do I remove the header and footer from the last page?
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
  <pre></pre>
  <p>
  </p>
  <pre></pre>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want to delete <code> tags and the content inside it.
as you can see, i tried doing it but somehow the <img> is not removed.
your solution might be good for this specific html, but i am looking for a more general approach which will remove all the content inside <code>

Comment: The <div class="page"> is not inside the <code> :) @Matan

Comment: it is inside the code, @UWTD TV

&lt;div class="page"&gt;
    &lt;img ...&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</code>

Comment: You are missing something https://i.imgur.com/w02o8iA.png @Matan